# SQL JOIN to find mismatches

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, join

I have two tables, naming products1 and products2 for simplicity, with the same schema:

```
(
  id int,
  name varchar(255),
  UNIQUE (id, name)
)
```

Technically it comes from a more complicated schema, but I simplified it like that.
I need to join them to find the mismatches.

Say products1 contains `(1, "name1") and (1, "name11"), and (3, "name3")`

And products2 contains `(1, "name1") and (1, "name11"), and (3, "name33"), and (4, "name4")`

Need to join them to find the mismatches in names, such as in the above case, mismatch would be `(id, old_name, new_name) = (3, "name3", "name33")`. Mismatches are those that are PRESENT in both tables, but names mismatch. Therefore, record for id=4 is not considered a mismatch.

I did a join, but due to the fact that an id can have multiple names, the results are a bit unexpected:

```
select p1.id, p1.name as old_name, p2.name as new_name
from products1 p1 join products2 p2 on p1.id = p2.id and p1.name <> p2.name
```

when (1, "name1") from products1 matches against (1, "name11") from products2, it outputs as mismatch. So I have three mismatches in total:

`(id, old_name, new_name) = 
  (1, "name1", "name11"), (1, "name11", "name1"), (3, "name3", "name33")`

However, there is another row from products1 that already matches that row in products2, so it should not be considered as a mismatch. what I am trying to achieve is only output `(3, "name3", "name33")` as mismatche. The other rows for `id = 1` should not be mismatches.

How can I achieve this through queries?

Note: running multiple queries is find, cuz this would run as multi steps in spark/scala.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use pure sql, this sounds like a job for `not exists`.
EDIT:
After the update to the OP:

```
select
p2.*
from
products2 p2
inner join products1 p1
    on p2.id = p1.id
where not exists
(select * from products1 p3
 where p3.id = p2.id
 and p3.name = p2.name)
```

And an updated [dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8mgyVn69aJ3unvkXwSXW1V/1)

Comment: sorry just added an update to the question. Forgot to mention one condition.

Comment: @Simo, made some updates, see if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to use `left join`:

```
select p2.*
from products2 p2
left outer join products1 p1 on p2.id=p1.id and p2.name=p1.name
where p1.id is null
```

Comment: just updated the question (at the end of the post) by adding one more condition. Can you update ur answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
select p1.id, p1.name, p2.name as name2 from
p1 join p2
on p1.id =p2.id and p1.name <> p2.name
```

get

```
id  name    name2
3   name3   name33
```

for

```
create table p1 (  id int,  name varchar(255));
create table p2 (  id int,  name varchar(255));
insert into p1 (id, name) values (1, 'name1'),(2, 'name11'), (3, 'name3');
insert into p2 (id, name) values (1, 'name1'),(2, 'name11'), (3, 'name33'),(4, "name4");
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/36806f/2

Comment: Pete, the id for name11 should still be 1, not 2. The main issue comes from the fact that an id can have multiple names,

Answer (score 0):

The following produces the list of names which are on only one ids, but whose ids have both names:

```
select id, name, max(which)
from (select p12.*,
             min(which) over (partition by id) as min_which,
             max(which) over (partition by id) as max_which
      from ((select p1.id, p1.name, 1 as which
             from products1 p1
            ) union all
            (select p2.id, p2.name, 2 as which
             from products2 p2
            )
           ) p12
     ) p12
where min_which = 1 and max_which = 2  -- id in both tables
group by id, name
having min(which) = max(which)  -- but name only in one table;
```

Your sample data is a bit limited.  I'm not sure what a single row would look like per id with more mismatches.

Answer (score 0):

In three queries:

1. Your query as it is now (saved as a table called "all")
2. Group "all" by id and save only those that have exactly one row in a table called "correct"
3. Select all rows from "all" where their id exists in "correct".

First query (save the results as table "all"):

```
SELECT p1.id, p1.name AS old_name, p2.name AS new_name
FROM products1 p1
JOIN products2 p2 ON p1.id = p2.id
WHERE p1.name <> p2.name
```

Second query (save the results as table "correct"):

```
SELECT id, COUNT(id) AS sum 
FROM all 
GROUP BY id 
HAVING sum = 1
```

Final query:

```
SELECT all.id, old_name, new_name 
FROM all 
JOIN correct ON all.id = correct.id
```

Output:

```
+---+--------+--------+
| id|old_name|new_name|
+---+--------+--------+
|  3|   name3|  name33|
+---+--------+--------+
```